# Javascript function gets overrun after consecutive setTimout calls

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've written a function to add a predefined div as a notification to the "notification_place" and one to remove the notification. To make it look more friendly and not that abrupt I wanted the notification/div to fade out before I remove it completly.

The issue I'm having is whenever a new notification/div is added while another one is still there the previous one can't be removed. The second however gets removed even though the have a different html ID. I get this issue just when I use a type of timeout function such as setTimeout or fadeTo in jquery. If I just write newdiv.remove() everything works as expected but it doesn't look they way I wanted it to.

```
var notification_place = 'notification_setting_position';

var new_message = '<div class="notification is-success" id="notification_msg_position_set"><h3 class="has-text-white"> Holder Position set!</h3></div>';
var new_message_id = 'notification_msg_position_set';

function addNotification(message) {
  let div = document.getElementById(notfification_place);
  div.innerHTML += message;
}


function removeNotification(msg_id){
  let newdiv = document.getElementById(msg_id);
  //newdiv.remove();

  $( "#"+msg_id ).fadeTo(500, 0, function(){newdiv.remove();}); 
}
```

or alternatively

```
function removeNotification(msg_id){
  let newdiv = document.getElementById(msg_id);
  newdiv.style.opacity='0';
  newdiv.addEventListener('transitionend', newdiv.remove());

}
```

and the CSS looking as follows

```
#notification_msg_setting_position {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

the HTML part looks something like this

```
<body>
   ...
         <div class="content">
            <h2>Status Feedback</h2>
         </div>
         <div class="content is-small" id="notification_setting_position">

         </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you also add the relevant html? Also a typo in your first function: `notfification_place`.

Comment: I updated my post with some further information

Comment: I can only think of a problem with variable scope. In your remove function try this:
`$( "#"+msg_id ).fadeTo(500, 0, function(){document.getElementById(msg_id).remove();}); `

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can try, but can you tell me how it is different from what I already tried: `function removeNotification(msg_id){
  let newdiv = document.getElementById(msg_id);
  $( "#"+msg_id ).fadeTo(500, 0, function(){newdiv.remove();}); 
}`